# validate response using jsr223 assertion

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have passed **chgId** as parameter in the get HTTP request.
*https://*******?chgId=405*

My api response is coming as -

```
{
  "response": {
    "data": [
      {
        "tid": 3697,
        "chgId": 405,
        "amount": 8.5,
        "Currency": "USD",
       },
      {
        "tid": 3698,
        "chgId": 405,
        "amount": 3.33,
        "Currency": "USD",
       
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now from the response I want to validate in JSR223 assertion that the response is correct based on the chgId field. That means in both 'data' array **"chgId": 405** text should come.

Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
def params = org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.parse(prev.getURL().toURI(), 'UTF-8')

def expected = params.find { 'chgId' }.value as int

def actual1 = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).response.data[0].chgId
def actual2 = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).response.data[1].chgId

def success = (expected == actual1 && expected == actual2)

if (!success) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('chgId mismatch')
}
```

where `prev` stands for **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)

More information:

- [URLEncodedUtils JavaDoc](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html)
- [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)